# Is hadoop a viable solution for managing batch processing of data on a single machine?

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I have a series of command line applications which take in raw data in the for of ~3GB data files. The apps are chained together to produce a much smaller output. I have a 6-core system and each application only needs a single core so I imagine I can run 6 in parallel.

I've been trying to automate this process (including collating the results) and have been reading up on Hadoop as a possible way to solve this problem.

Is Hadoop a suitable solution for this and if so, what bits of it should I be using (or is there something else that's better suited)?

**Edit**

Just to make this a bit clearer, the rough pipeline looks like this:

```
     .-> [A] -> W1 -> [B] -> X1 -> [C] -> Y1 -.
    /                                          \
V -<                                            >- [D] -> Z
    \                                          /
     `-> [M] -> W2 -> [B] -> X2 -> [C] -> Y2 -`
```

..where

- `[A, B, C, D]` are the command-line applications.
- `V` is one 3GB data file (of which there are several hundred and counting).
- `W1` & `W2` are ~3MB intermediate files.
- `X1` & `X2` are ~200KB intermediate files.
- `Y1` & `Y2` are ~200KB intermediate files.
- `Z` is the final report.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement. If your data is going to get increase and it is in raw or unstructured format as you said then hadoop can help you here.

1. You can use [map-reduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html)  for giving it a series of inputs, will produce the output which is given to reducer based on key and list of values. You can use different ways for map-reduce and programming languages. You will get more information about hadoop [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/).
2. If you have a processing like taking data from a file or db , process it and store the output back into file or db, and your data is comparatively smaller(As it said hadoop is usually used when you have really huge data in TB's )  then you can also take a look at [spring-batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not using Hadoop unless you really need it.

So in your case, based on what you said and the reasonable amount of data, it does not make sense to pay the cost of using Hadoop.

My 2 cents.

Comment: Any suggestions of an alternative option? ...or should I just roll my own in Python (which was my original thinking)?